# How to set columWidth config at runtime in ExtJs columnLayout?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a panel with some items in it, it's initial layout is column and each item have `columnWidth: 1` but now on a button click event I want to set `columnWidth` of each item to 0.5. which should be 50% of the container.

I have tried:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    vertical: true,
    layout: 'column',
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'button', 
        id:'btn1', 
        width: 80,
        text: 'Button1', 
        columnWidth:1
        },{
        xtype: 'button', 
        id:'btn2', 
        width: 80, 
        text: 'Button2', 
        columnWidth:.2
        }
    ]
}
```

button click code:

```
Ext.getCmp('btn2').setConfig({columnWidth: '1'});
```

but this is not working please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code was not laid out properly using the "Code Sample" button. I have done that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't have `columnWidth: 1`. From [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-columnWidth):

> The `columnWidth` property is always evaluated as a percentage and must
>   be a decimal value greater than 0 and **less than 1** (e.g., .25).

To update your `columnWidth`dynamically, set its value on the item directly and then update the whole layout:

```
handler: function() {
    Ext.getCmp('btn2').columnWidth = 0.5;
    Ext.getCmp('panel').updateLayout();
}
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pjm